# C# ASP .net reportviewer-table control question

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Can i set any cell attributes dynamically of a report file from the c# code in its host 'report.aspc' page.

I have a db and have added a report.rdcl to my solution, i have also put a reportViewer component into my report.aspx page. I get the data displaying ok but i want to color certain rows etc based on data itself.